# Matlab Coder Convert variable-size cell error

Tags: c++, matlab

I use **Matlab coder** to convert .m files into .cpp files.

But the Build Errors tells me:

> Code generation is not supported for variable-size cell arrays via
>   the cell function.

And I have referred to the method at the following site:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/cell-array-restrictions-for-code-generation.html#bvczero

But it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
--------------------------------------------------
dets = mycell(n, 1);
...
%-------------------------------- 
function z = mycell(n,m)
%--------------------------------
%#codegen
assert(n < 100);
assert(m < 100);
x = cell(n,m);   
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:m 
        x{i,j} = i+j;
    end
end
z = x{m,n};
```

Is there any problem with this code?

Comment: Format code as code please.

Comment: can it be because you are not ending the function with the `end` keyword after `z = x{m,n};` ?

Comment: Did you try `coder.nullcopy`? https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/unable-to-determine-that-every-element-of-cell-array-is-assigned.html#bve4djh

Comment: Also, are you on the latest version of MATLAB? If not, you're reading documentation that doesn't match your software...

Comment: One minor edit is needed: if `function z=mycell(n,m)`, then: `z=x{n,m}` and not `z=x{m,n}`

Comment: It is a subfunction of another function, so I doesn't add the `end` after `z = x{m,n};` @FedericoMilani

Comment: Sorry, it's `z=x{n,m}`. I have corrected it but it still doesn't work.  @MehrdadZandigohar

Comment: I use Matlab 2015b. Is it necessary for me to update it into Matlab 2017?  @CrisLuengo

Comment: Yes, I have tried once, but it still tells me error. **Code generation is not supported for variable-size cell arrays via the cell function** @CrisLuengo

Comment: I'm using Matlab 2017a and the code mentioned in your post works fine for me. So, if even this code does not work for you, so an upgrade to a newer version is recommended. @JasonZheng

Comment: @JasonZheng: if you are using MATLAB 2015b, look at the documentation for that version. It is very possible that this construct was not legal in that version, even if it's a example in the documentation for the current version. MATLAB coder changes rapidly, lots of things are possible now that weren't possible 2 years ago.

Comment: OK, I will have a try. Thanks. @MehrdadZandigohar

Answer (score 0):

I have made a new file to put mycell function, but not as a subfunction.

And I find an error at the site:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/cell-array-restrictions-for-code-generation.html#bvczero

We should change the code
`z = x{m,n};` 
into 
`z = x;`

And finally the coder works.

Thank you all very much!